# SQL server Grouping using different rows merge in One Rows

Tags: sql-server

Some rows values like this

[image]

Now i want to do grouping on this want a Single result in Single rows, Also whenever there is a  Two Values for same week use case like this e.g : Week4  Merge "Yes" and "No" in "Yes" .

[image]

Comment: Your table design is not so great. You should better change it. Read up on *Normalization*

Comment: What query have you got so far?

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is not so great. You should better change it. Read up on *Normalization*

But if you can't change it then use

```
select studentcode, modulecode, eventtype, semester,
       max(week1) as week1,
       max(week2) as week2,
       max(week3) as week3,
       max(week4) as week4,
       max(week5) as week5,
       max(week6) as week6,
       max(week7) as week7,
       max(week8) as week8,
       max(week9) as week9,
       max(week10) as week10,
       max(week11) as week11,
       max(week12) as week12,
from your_table
group by studentcode, modulecode, eventtype, semester
```

Comment: Hi Juergen d, Thanks for Answer It's work for me what result i want. I haven't design a Table, data is uploaded from Excel file.